# Font size decreases when changing page (fixes on refresh)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm literally at the end of my patience with this one. I'm working on a mobile site, but there is a huge, unexplainable bug that I can't fix.

I use a Jquery script to swap between pages, it creates a new div tag, puts the new content inside it, slides it above the old content, then removes the old content from the DOM completely. That works fine, except when I change page, the font size decreases, by probably 10 pixels. The line height appears to change too. I check the code with Google's element inspector, and it says the text is at 30 pixels, but when I refresh the page, it grows bigger, but still says 30 pixels.

I'm stumped, I truly am. I have no idea of the cause as I have one tag that controls the font size, and no others have any effect on it.

Here's the Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function anchorClick(link) {

        var linkSplit = link.split('/').pop();
        console.log(linkSplit);
        $.get('/pages/'+linkSplit, function(data) {

            $("#top").append("<div class=\"content2\" id=\"c2\">hello world</div>")
            $('.content')
            .queue(function(n) {
            $('.content2').html(data);
            n();
            $('.content2').animate({ marginTop: '0px', top: '0px'}, 1000);
            $('.content').delay(1000).fadeOut(100, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            $('#c2').addClass('content').removeClass('content2').removeAttr('id');
            });

            })
            ;
        });

    }

    $('body').on('click', 'a.loader', function(e) {

        window.history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));

        anchorClick($(this).attr('href'));


        e.preventDefault();

    });

    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {

        anchorClick(location.pathname);     

    });
});
```

Relevant CSS styles:

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
}
.content2 {
    margin-top:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:120%;
    background:#DCDEE3;
    min-height:100%;
}
.content {
    background:#DCDEE3;
}
#top {
width:100%;
background:#DCDEE3;
}
.pdata{
    font-size:30px;!important
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

And this is basically the HTML that is loaded into the page:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="mainbox2 boxy">
  <h1>
  About
  </h1>
    <div class="pdata">
    CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The bug seems to shrink all of the text on the page, not just specific elements.
I'd recreate this in a JSFiddle but it requires loading from PHP scripts and such

Edit: This only seems to happen in mobile view or on mobile phones. When loading a new page, the font sizes decreases by about 50% for literally no reason. Changing font to 22 pixels shows the font in size 22, until I load another page, then it decides to just shrink it for no reason.

Comment: Most probably not related, but CSS in your example has syntax error:  `!important` after semicolon. So the font-family declaration fails.

Also, are you sure it is just font-size that decreases? Couldn't it be full page zoom?

Comment: Oops, I fixed the `!important`, thanks. And no, it's not full page zoom as all of the images are the same. It is literally just the font

Comment: I've narrowed it down to something to do with the way the script works. When I remove the fancy effects, and set it so it just changes the content of `.content`, there are no problems. It seems creating a new div class stops it working

Comment: @myf Narrowed **even further** down. It seems to be due to the use of position absolute/fixed on `.content2`. It needs to be absolute or fixed positioned for the effect to work, but it seems to shrink the text size.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the answer to this question. It turns out that the browser (Chrome on Android was the testing browser across multiple devices) automatically makes font sizes bigger if you don't apply a `height` attribute. These reasons are unclear. Adding `max-height:99999px;` to the relevant div elements did the trick. All font sizes are correct now.

Comment: It so weird chrome has this bug. I got this issue with heading tags in Chrome mobile browser desktop site. This hack works. Thank you :)